# Iterating through a CSV and pulling out the last line of the day for each element

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk

I asked this yesterday and didn't get a working answer but much of it was failing to be specific enough.

I've got an interesting problem I'm not quite sure how best to tackle, with iterating through a list. With the following format -

```
element, date, unixTime, before, after
CZ, 12/27/07 3:55 PM, 1198788900, 42345, 42346
CZ, 12/27/07 5:30 PM, 1198794600, 42346, 42300
CZ, 12/27/07 7:05 PM,1198800300, 42300, 42000
JB, 12/27/07 7:05 PM,1198800300, 13722, 13500
I, 12/27/2007 7:05 PM, 1198800300, 4475, 4572
```

I want to iterate through, for each unique element and for each date, and get the sign of the change in the before/after columns. For instance, I would want 3 lines for 12/27/2007, for CZ JB and I. There are millions of lines, sometimes thousands for each day, and I just need to print of the last line for each element of the day. So there's multiple, maybe hundreds or thousands, of "CZ" lines for 12/27. I just need to pull out that last one, and print to output "CZ, 12/27/07, 1" or "CZ, 12/27/07, -1". For 12/27, the last line of CZ is a negative direction so it prints -1. And it would do the same for JB, and I, and all the other elements. The file is sorted by unix time, and the elements can be mixed up. I would want the output to look like the following

```
element, date, direction
CZ, 12/27/07, -1
JB, 12/27/07, -1
I, 12/27/07, 1
CZ, 12/28/07, 1
JB, 12/27/07, -1
I, 12/27/07, -1
```

Trying to figure out a succinct way in bash, python, perl, or even something like awk to do something like this. For each day, it will have a direction for each element that has at least one line during that day. I considered slow methods of doing so like reading through the file, populating an "elements" and "dates" table, then doing a foreach and comparing each set to find the largest unix time and then print with that, but there's got to be a much better way to run through it once instead.

Comment: Please, _please_, show us that which you have done.  It helps a lot for a question to be legitimate for SO

Comment: when I see a question with "I want the *last* line where ..." I tend to think: reverse the file, then find the *first* line where ...

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a `dict` of `dict`s application.

Since you can count on overwriting the value with the most recent one, in unixtime, you can just dynamically build a `dict`, keyed by date, and then add `dict`s therein for each element.

```
import csv

d = {}
with open('inputfile.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        element = row[0]
        date = row[1]
        before = float(row[3])
        after = float(row[4])

        if date not in d:
              d[date] = {}

        if before < after:
              d[date][element] =  1
        else:
              d[date][element] = -1
```

If you need the output to necessarily be in order by date, you can grab the dates and sort them.

```
from datetime import datetime
dates = [datetime.strptime(date.split(None)[0], '%y/%m/%d') 
         for date d.keys()]
sorted(dates)
```

Otherwise you can just grab the dates as strings as is.

```
dates = d.keys()
```

Then just write the output file

```
with open('outfile.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(['element', 'date', 'direction'])
    for date in dates:
        for element in d[date]:
            writer.writerow([delement, date, d[date][element]])
```

Comment: Note that on line 8 you need to grab only the date part and discard the time, like I do in line 5 of my code. Also, you could use a `collections.defaultdict` in line 3 in order to avoid lines 12 and 13 and you could even store it all in a single dictionary instead of nested dictionaries by using a tuple of `(date, element)` as your key.

Comment: Oh, and your last 4 lines can be written as one: `d[date][element] = 1 if before < after else 1`. It makes things more readable when you get used to it.

Comment: @JosepValls: It would be a good idea to *test* your own solution before you go criticising other people's solutions

Comment: @heyiamt: `before` and `after` are `row[3]` and `row[4]`

Comment: @JosepValls I agree that there's a fair amount of compression that can go on in the example. I thought it prudent to be a bit more pedantic, but perhaps that's an unfair assessment of the OP's python background

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider using groupby

If your data is already in this format:

```
[
['CZ', '12/27/07 3:55 PM', '1198788900', '42345', '42346',],
['CZ', '12/27/07 5:30 PM', '1198794600', '42346', '42300',],
['CZ', '12/27/07 7:05 PM','1198800300', '42300', '42000',],
['JB', '12/27/07 7:05 PM','1198800300', '13722', '13500',],
['I', '12/27/07 7:05 PM', '1198800300', '4475', '4572']
]
```

Then you can do this:

```
#truncate out the time portion of the second col:
for row in data:
    row[1] = row[1].split(" ")[0]

#sort by symbol and date    
data = sorted(data, key = lambda x: (x[0], int(x[2]))) 
from itertools import groupby

for k, g in groupby(data, lambda x:x[:2]):
    before,after = list(g)[-1][-2:] #extracts the last line.
    k.append( "1" if int(after) > int(before) else "-1" )
    print ",".join(k)
```

With the following output:

```
CZ,12/27/07,-1
I,12/27/07,1
JB,12/27/07,-1
```

Comment: The OP mentions that the file is already sorted and there are "millions'' of lines so I avoided assuming that the data is already loaded and avoided resorting it. In my experience, if the data is NOT already sorted, when working with big files you are better sorting it OUTSIDE of Python (with the `sort` command)

Answer (score 0):

Perl (tested):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($inputfile, %output) = "input.csv";
open (my $pfile, '<', "$inputfile") or die "Couldn't open file '$inputfile'\n";

<$pfile>; #  SKIPS HEADER LINE, delete if there is no header present

while (my $row = <$pfile>) {
    die "Malformed line: $row" if $row !~ /^\s*(\S+)\s*,\s*(\d\d\/\d\d\/)(\d\d)(\d\d)?\s[^,]*,[^,]*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*$/;
    my ($element, $date, $before, $after) = ($1, $2.($4 ? $4 : $3), $5, $6);
    $output{$element . $date} = [ $element, $date, $before - $after < 0 ? -1 : 1 ];
}
close $pfile;

print join(',', @$_)."\n" foreach ([ "element", "date", "direction" ], values %output);
```

Answer (score 0):

In GNU awk (regex `FS`). It only buffers the previous (and current) records so it expects sorted input file and for once the size doesn't matter:

```
$ awk -F"(, |,| )" -v OFS="," '
p!=($1 OFS $2) && NR>1 {                                 # when $1 and $2 change
    print p, q                                           # print previous
}
{
    p=$1 OFS $2                                          # set previous 
    q=$7-$6
    q=( q ? q/sqrt(q^2) : ( NR==1 ? "direction" : 0 ) )  # determine -1,0,1
}
END {
    print p, q                                           # last line handling
}
' file

element,date,direction
CZ,12/27/07,-1
JB,12/27/07,-1
I,12/27/2007,1
```